# How to get first numeric character with preg_match?

Tags: php

I have phone number. If the first numeric character of a number is not 1 I need to add it. I can't find out how to do it with preg_match, or is there any other way?

```
$first_number = $number;
if(preg_match('something', $first_number, $result))
{
$first_number = '1'. $result[1];
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the FIRST CHARACTER of the string is a 1, or whether the first numeric character WITHIN the string is a 1?  I.e. "+46010398765" might be a Swedish phone number.  How do you handle it?

Comment: A Swedish number is perhaps not the best example.  I'm in North America, so technically my phone number starts with "+1".  So is "+" the first character, and should a "1" therefore be prepended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not need to go for regex here. You can do:

```
if($first_number[0] != '1') {
    $first_number = '1'.$first_number;
}
```

But if the number can have leading spaces or a `+` sign you can do:

```
if(preg_match('/^(\D*)(\d)/',$first_number,$match))
    $first_number = $match[1].'1'.$match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first non-numeric character isn't always at position 1 in the array, if I'm reading your question right.

```
$n="foo 415";
preg_match("/^[^0-9]*([0-9])/", $n, $matches);
print $matches[0]."\n";'
```

returns `4`.

Comment: If that is the question, Ghoti's answer works. If the question is that a number should only be matched if the number does not start with a '1', then my answer works. Pick one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `preg_match` or `preg_replace` here, the simple solution below should work

```
if ($number[0] != 1)
{
  $number.= '1'. $number;
}
```

Comment: And if my number is `+14159876543`, what happens?

Comment: The problem is not to replace the 1st character of string.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
'/^([^1][0-9]+)$/'
```

It should do the trick!